# PLS-00103 error while executing a sql block (Encountered the symbol "SELECT" ...)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to learn PLSQL and this is a code that I been trying to execute, When I execute the code I get the following error.

```
ORA-06550: line 2, column 7:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:

   ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
   continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev
   sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval
   date <a string literal with character set specification>
   <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe
   <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification>
   <an alternat
ORA-06550: line 2, column 58:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:

   * & - + ; / at for mod remainder rem <an exponent (**)> and
   or group having intersect minus order start union where
   connect || multiset
```

I know you can assign a variable to the select statement and use that variable in IF statement, I just want to know the error in the following code.

```
BEGIN
  IF((SELECT marks FROM students WHERE student_id ='s10')= 'Passed') THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello!');
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: The error is that using a `SELECT` inside the `IF` clause of the statement is invalid syntax. It may work in other RDBMS but not in Oracle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
begin 
for i in (SELECT marks FROM students WHERE student_id ='s10') loop
    if i.marks = 'Passed' then 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello!');
    end if;
end loop;
end;
```

OR with a variable if the student_id is unique

```
declare
v_mark students.marks%type;
begin 
SELECT marks into v_mark FROM students WHERE student_id ='s10';
    if v_mark = 'Passed' then 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello!');
    end if;
end;
```

Comment: Yes both of them works, Thank you. But Can you please explain why my code didn't work?

Comment: You cannot directly use a SQL statement in a PL/SQL expression, u need to use a variable or cursor variable, PL/SQL and SQL are not the same language and that s how a PL/SQL syntax simply is.

Comment: Sorry for my incompetence, Can you explain the first code to me? What is the purpose of the 'for'?

Comment: Its called 'FOR Loop Cursor statement',  it loops  through a implicit cursor (select statement) that we dont need to declare in declare block (thats why its called "implicit"). All in all it is not a very efficient way of extracting or checking data in a table thats why its rarely used in real projects, at least where i m working :)

Comment: If you are confused why m I saying u can t directly use SQL statements in PL/SQL expression and u need to use a variable but I did it in the 'for loop', the thing is that the select statement in my for loop is still viewed as a cursor variable but in your if statement it is not, u can t make an implicit cursor in if-s condition.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining that to me, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using a cursor:

```
declare
cursor c1 is SELECT marks FROM students WHERE student_id ='s10';
begin
for r1 in c1 loop
    if r1.marks = 'Passed' then 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello!');
    end if; 
end loop; 
end;
```